# 777-300ER venting something from left engine outboard side - what is it?

Tags: aircraft-systems, engine, boeing-777, contrails

Crossposting from [Metabunk](https://www.metabunk.org/threads/highly-asymmetric-trail-with-no-gap-by-engine.13070) with permission from the thread opener marko.posavec.

[image: photo by Metabunk user marko.posavec]

Their photo shows British Airways Boeing 777-300ER G-STBF in flight with something producing a contrail or the like from the outboard side of #1 engine.

What is/could be causing this?

Comment: It might simply be that the de-icing is on and that is melting ice from the cowl's lips

Comment: Ice and de-ice at 36000 ft?

Comment: Proof positive that the chemtrail phenomenon is real :;

Comment: Wild hypothesis: some sort of un-evenness in cowl / nacelle that is causing turbulence and triggering condensation?

Comment: @CptReynolds only a theory, just like all the other ones

Comment: Cowls are are evaporatively anti-iced. They are kept above the boiling point so supercooled waterdroplets turn to steam right away on contact. If ice formation is allowed, it can damage blades.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it's not condensate water from the tail pipe, and it looks to be originating from the main cowl, so it can only be one of the Big Three fluids; fuel, engine oil, or hydraulic oil (for the reversers, assuming they're hydraulically driven). Such leaks are not [unheard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Transat_Flight_236) of.

If I was flying 2000 ft below them on the same track so that I was able to observe that for a while, I'd probably contact ATC to relay to them my observations.

Comment: This was taken when the aircraft crossed Romania inbound LHR from BOM, so it probably had been ongoing for a while, or would it start mid-flight? In any case, the flight didn't divert and the aircraft remained in service for another flight about 3 hrs after landing. So at least it wasn't as dire as the Air Transat one.

Comment: re "so it can only be one of the Big Three fluids" -- consider https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/100213/777-300er-venting-something-from-left-engine-outboard-side-what-is-it#comment279711_100213

Comment: Yes of course. Does anyone have the QRH for these three leaks at their fingertips? I'm cut off from mine for another couple of days... probably not far off from "land nearest suitable" for some of these, right?

Comment: Possibly a leak could make a noticeable contrail and be too small to even notice fuel quantity wise and go undetected for a while. Or possibly it's just a fluid like engine oil venting off for some reason.