What is this thin stream coming out from somewhere near the engine?
A friend of mine have recently had a flight from Rome to NYC, on a B-787 (Norse Atlantic), and he noticed this thin stream coming out from somewhere in the engine area, seen in this video. From his seat he could not see where exactly it's coming from. It started when the engine started, and continued throughout the entire flight.

My first thought was that it's something to do with the air-conditioning or pressurization system, but since i couldn't identify the exact location the steam is coming from, i can't say for sure.
Any idea?

Possibly related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/100213/10025

It is oil from the combined drain mast and breather outlet. Norse uses RR trent 1000. The drain is for any water that gets into the cowling but empties on the ground and the breather is for the air/oil separator for oil that gets past various seals in the engine. Exhaust is normally only visible on the ground. At speed the air pressure increases and seals work properly. If visible in the air there was likely a damaged oil seal.

Here is a cutaway of the similar trent 500 showing part 52 (click to view full-size image):


No chemtrail then, what a pity

@sophit Oil is a chemical. Come to think of it, water is a molecule and also thus a chemical.

@slebetman: everything is actually chemical  But you know that I meant this.

The default behavior is for the image  tag to point to the uploaded image, but you can change that (as I did) so that it points to the original. Or indeed to any other URL.

I had the feeling that mentioning the airline will be important for the answer, I just didn't know how... thank you @Pilothead!

@sophit Literally a "chemtrail" for once
